# Magento edit form

Tags: php, magento

Всем привет. Столкнулся с проблемой в magento2. Нужно создать модуль, в котором будут input, чтобы можно было при их заполнение эти данные сохранить в БД.
Если подскажите статью или любую информацию, буду благодарен.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/89141/save-a-simple-text-input-form-to-database-from-custom-admin-controller - немного не то, но для начала пойдёт.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/166406/insert-form-data-into-database/166459

Comment: misdeed это для Magento 1. Я нуждаюсь в помощи magento 2

Comment: там же ищите, на magento.SE

Comment: Со своего личного опыта не можете помочь?

Comment: к счастью, такого опыта не было)